# SO new fonts: is `Cascadia mono` a mistake and it was meant to be` Cascadia code` instead?

Tags: discussion, bug

On 10th of may 2021, SO fonts changed from {Arial, Consolas} to {Segoe UI, Cascadia mono}.

I think that instead of any "Cascadia Mono", they meant "Cascadia Code Light" or so, which is IMHO a lot more appropriate because of its ligatures and readability (try those with each):

```
iI 1 lL  oO0  rn m  __global__ <= --> <==
```

Cascadia code:

[image: cascadia code]

Cascadia mono:

[image: cascadia mono]

Comment: The ligatures make it _less_ clear what's been typed.

Comment: The font changes are network-wide and not SO-specific so this is better posted on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021?cb=1#)...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I don't post **code** in math.overflow for instance.

Comment: @Soleil There are many sites about code. Just because there is one site without code does not mean this would not be a network wide problem.

Comment: I'm going to let the designers answer, but I'm going to go out on a limb and say "No, it was not a mistake between Cascadia mono and Cascadia code". I understand the font choices are not to your liking. People hated the previous design when it showed up. Let's give it a few days for our brains to adjust. You have options to change the fonts if you don't want to let your brain adjust. But raising a [bug] for every design thing you don't like just gets tiresome.

Comment: Do you have any other reason for this than "it looks more readable"? At a glance, it seems the ligatures would be misleading for code – in many languages ``a ≤ b`` is something entirely different than ``a <= b``, and ligatures would hide the difference.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No. In which programming language (except LateX) is ≤ used ?

Comment: @Soleil That's kind of my point. Seeing ``a ≤ b`` would indicate a syntax error in most languages. Ligatures would require going the extra mile to check whether its a literal ≤ or a ligature <=. (Julia accepts both, by the way.)

Comment: @Soleil P.S. I'm not _sure_, but I think your texting text would be more useful starting with a _lowercase_ L, like `IIll`. Maybe include some 1's as well... `IIll11`.

Comment: The font change has been a big problem on Stack Overflow. The number of characters available for code has been reduced from 90 to 82 causing all of the nicely formatted older answers to wrap. Much care was taken to provide code and answers that formatted correctly and avoided wrapping. All of that effort has been lost and the site display of past answers suffers as a result.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin What odd terminal sizes do you use? It's 80 characters. 79 of them for code plus one for +/-/… of diffs. 

Comment: @BlackJack - this change occurred around, or as part of, the dark theme roll-out as I recall. I'll have to put the old drive back in, but I suspect the font used was Dejavu Sans Mono (book). For a couple of years prior to the change I set my right-margin line at 90 characters and all posts fit perfectly in the SO window without generating scroll bars. When the change occurred, I had to reset the guide at 80 characters for the same effect. There are many occasions at 80 chars you have to break function parameters on separate lines, etc..

Answer (score 20):

Ligatures are only useful for a limited set of languages. For example in LaTeX beamer, they make zero sense:

[image]

(hint: `2-` belongs together as a logical group and the `<>` around are like brackets)

Ligatures would be a really bad default choice.

Comment: Ligatures are fine (if you like them). If they don’t make sense at any point, this can be handled in highlight.js: wrap the number with the hyphen in its own `<span>` and apply the CSS rule `font-variant-ligatures: none;` to it. Alternatively, apply `span::after { content: "\200b" }`.